# CIBA and contextual authentication

Tags: openid-connect

For CIBA based flows, how can risk based (contextual) authentication based on device telemetry play a role ? Has anyone had any experience with factoring device trust and integrity into enabling a CIBA flow ? Just keen to understand how this can be used.

Thanks,
Diego